# Running executable in C code

Tags: c, macos

I am writing in C (not C++) on a Mac. I want to be able to run a UNIX executable from C, something like this:

```
#include <some-wacky-header.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int r = some_wacky_executable_run(path_to_my_file_as_char_array);
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I don't want to use the `system()` command to run the executable.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use `system()`?

Comment: I hate it when people ask questions with nonsensical conditions attached. If you insist on denying `system` then give a justification for doing so.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Such nonsensical conditions are quite common in homework assignments...

Answer (score 4):

How about `exec()`?  It replaces your running program with another one, rather than having both run like `system()` does.

`popen()` is another option, though I imagine if you don't like `system()` (why?), you won't like that either.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `fork()` + `exec()`, since this allows the original process to continue working in parallel. Unless you tell us why you do not want to use `system()`, however, there is no way to be sure that *this* solution would be acceptable for you. `popen()` is another alternative, if you need access to the standard input or output of the called executable.